# Concurrency with Sqlite3 and Flask using Gunicorn

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, gunicorn

I have a Flask app that connects to Sqlite3 using Flask-SQL Alchemy.  When I run the app on Gunicorn with a single worker, the app performs as expected. However, whenever I run  the app with more than 1 worker, some queries fail to return data.

I attached the pid to my logs, to track the processes. After some digging, I found that the first worker process initialized by the Gunicorn master process, can access the database without issue. However, any subsequent workers always return empty data.

I suspect that, since the process are initialized within ~100ms of each over, the first process connects to the database, but blocks subsequent processes. Since the other processes were unable to connect, they don't return any data. However, I don't get any exceptions.

My first thought is to have a some sort of function to check if the database is being blocked when connecting, and to retry until the block is lifted by the previous process. However, I couldn't find anything about that in the SQL Alchemy documentation.

Even, if I could do that, I'm still concerned that I would run into more problems down the road, if concurrent process try to write to the database simultaneously. Is there a way to manage this situation using SQL Alchemy, without switching to a sever-based DBMS?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.